# Unable to create payment on stripe

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I created a customer and now when I am trying to deduct payment it is giving me an error "Required Action"

Here is the code to create customer and deduct payment

What I want is to save the customer's details and deduct the payment later. It is not necessary that the amount be deducted at the same time.

```
app.post('/create-customer', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // Create a PaymentMethod from the token
        const paymentMethod = await stripe.paymentMethods.create({
            type: 'card',
            card: {
                token: req.body.token,
            },
        });

        // Create a customer and attach the PaymentMethod
        const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
            name: 'Abxxxx kumar',
            email: 'xxxxx@gmail.com', // Replace with the customer's email
            payment_method: paymentMethod.id,
            invoice_settings: {
                default_payment_method: paymentMethod.id,
            },
        });

        res.status(200).json({ customer });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred while creating the customer.' });
    }
});


const deductAmount = async () => {
    try {
        const amount = 1000; // Adjust the amount as needed
        console.log(" ~ Deducting amount:", amount);

     
        const customerID = 'cus_Oas7xxxxx1BCrv';

        // Retrieve the customer's default PaymentMethod (assuming you have it stored)
        const customer = await stripe.customers.retrieve(customerID);
        const defaultPaymentMethod = customer.invoice_settings.default_payment_method;

        if (!defaultPaymentMethod) {
            throw new Error('Customer does not have a default payment method.');
        }

        // Create a PaymentIntent with automatic confirmation and disable redirects
        const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
            amount: parseInt(amount) * 100,
            currency: 'usd',
            customer: customerID,
            payment_method: defaultPaymentMethod,
            confirm: true, // Set to true for automatic confirmation
            automatic_payment_methods: {
                enabled: true,
                allow_redirects: 'never',
            },
        });

        if (paymentIntent.status === 'succeeded') {
            console.log(" Payment succeeded. PaymentIntent ID:", paymentIntent.id);
            // You can store the PaymentIntent ID or other relevant information in your database.
        } else {
            console.error("❌ Payment failed. PaymentIntent status:", paymentIntent.status);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("❌ Error:", error.message);
    }
};
```

Expected output is payment success, as this is in test mode

Answer (score 0):

The "Required Action" error typically occurs when a PaymentIntent requires additional actions to be taken by the customer before the payment can be completed. This can happen for various reasons, such as 3D Secure authentication, SCA (Strong Customer Authentication) checks, or other verification steps depending on the card, bank, or payment method being used.

In your code, you've set `confirm: true` when creating the PaymentIntent, which means you're attempting to confirm the payment immediately. If there are any additional actions required, you'll get a "Required Action" error.

To handle this scenario, you should implement a webhook to listen for and handle the `payment_intent.requires_action` event. This event will inform you when additional actions are needed to complete the payment, and you can then redirect the customer to the relevant authentication flow.

Here's how you can modify your code to handle this:

1. Set up a webhook endpoint in your application to receive Stripe events. You can use a library like `stripe-node` to handle webhooks.

```js
const stripe = require('stripe')(YOUR_STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

// Endpoint to handle Stripe webhook events
app.post('/webhook', async (req, res) => {
  const event = req.body;

  try {
    // Handle the event based on its type
    switch (event.type) {
      case 'payment_intent.requires_action':
        // Additional action required, handle it here
        // You might want to redirect the customer to complete the action
        // See the Stripe documentation for handling this event
        break;
      case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
        // Payment succeeded, handle it here
        console.log('Payment succeeded:', event.data.object.id);
        break;
      default:
        // Handle other events if needed
    }

    res.json({ received: true });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error handling webhook event:', error);
    res.status(500).end();
  }
});
```

2. When creating the PaymentIntent, set `confirm: false` to prevent immediate confirmation:

```js
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
  amount: parseInt(amount) * 100,
  currency: 'usd',
  customer: customerID,
  payment_method: defaultPaymentMethod,
  confirm: false, // Set to false for manual confirmation
});
```

3. After creating the PaymentIntent, return the `client_secret` in your response to your front-end. You'll need this `client_secret` to confirm the PaymentIntent on the client-side when additional actions are required.
4. On the front-end, handle the scenario where the PaymentIntent status is `requires_action`. You can use the Stripe.js library to handle the redirection or additional actions as needed.

By implementing these changes, you'll be able to handle scenarios where additional actions are required to complete the payment and respond accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if a PaymentIntent is in a "requires_action" status, it means you need to ask the user to come back to your website/app and then confirm the PaymentIntent on the frontend with [`stripe. confirmCardPayment()`](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment#stripe_confirm_card_payment-attached).

Note that the code you shared is using Tokens and PaymentIntent at the same time, which doesn't make sense. Tokens are an old integration that shouldn't be used. I recommend following [this guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements) to accept a payment instead.

Comment: but i need to save something for future payment can you please provide me something about that

Comment: When you create the PaymentIntent, set the [`setup_future_usage`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-setup_future_usage) property.

Comment: after reading stripe doc i create customer and add card details.  but after doing all the thing subscription is created for the reccuring payment but in invoice status is come as pending is there any soltuion for it.

Please refer the docs for code
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1KNbcYf9AUKY0CnUJZbDxs5VR63gpLVf5Nm6Cx8mUPaQ/edit

Comment: If you are using Subscriptions, then no need to create a PaymentIntent. Instead follow [this guide](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=elements).